# React hooks get previous state of state A when setting state of state B

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, if I have two pieces of state:

```js
const [a, setA] = useState(0);
const [b, setB] = useState(0);
```

And I want to update b using the previous state of both a and b, is there a way to do it without grouping them in an object?

It seems that you can only update the state using the previous state of the same piece of state, like so:

```js
setB(b => b + 1)
```

Comment: why don't setB(a+b)?

Comment: Because the values of a and b might be stale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized recently that the best solution here is to use the `useReducer` hook.

Answer (score 2):

you can use hook [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and add in dependencies variable **a**

```
const setVariable = useCallback(() => {
    setB(b => b + a)
}, [a]);
```